# How to convert rewarded ads coins to currency?

Tags: android, react-native, admob

I have an app that has rewarded ads using AdMob, now when a video advertisement is viewed I can see the reward having coins returned but how can I implement a way of converting those coins into what it is worth in currency value based like USD for example?

I am trying to implement a feature where users can watch ads and for that they can get coins to have discount on product prices depending on coins they have collected.

Can anyone tell me how to convert coins to actual value?

UPDATE: I am using `react-native-firebase` for viewing ads which is documented here: https://rnfb-docs.netlify.app/admob/displaying-ads#rewarded-ads

Answer (score 1):

Be vary cautious of what you do. I am on a 30 day suspension because of this. Rethink your strategy. Apperantly real money in exchange for ads being watched on admob is prohibited.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think whats said in the image though is not related to what you said. I think they meant you should allow users to watch ads by some other way for example if they have an interest on viewing a feature in your app you show them an ad or if they collect some certain rewards they get real money for it. Some platforms in Playstore  already have that why they're not suspended then?

Comment: I made a app that you watch videos gain points and exchange points for real money... That's what the multi clicking is... The email is a mile long and goes indepth. Admob you can not have multiple clicks or having people multiclick on your ads. I was running almost 500 ad requests per device per day.. luckily it was just testing but they specifically said offering money in exchange for ad views is prohibited